# "I won't stay longer than I can help" or "longer than I can't help"?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I've come across the following sentence recently:

> "I won't stay longer than I can help."

I've heard similar uses of "can help" in other contexts and they all sounded strange to me.  Shouldn't we say :

> "I won't stay longer than I can't help."

In the same manner, doesn't it sound strange to say:

> "I'm not driving at night, unless I can help it"

Shouldn't one say "unless I can't help it"?

Comment: I think you've identified an illogical expression, along the lines of *"I could care less"* rather than *"I couldn't care less"*. For *"unless I can't help it"*, people use both *"can"* and *"can't"*, and searching in Google books it seems roughly 50-50.

Comment: It's not illogical. "The length of my stay *won't exceed* the length of time in which I am able to help."; "I'll be here as long as I can help; when I can no longer help, I will leave".

Comment: @PeterShor: +1, although I will note that "I could care less" may be viewed as an elliptical rendering of "[As if] I could care less."

Comment: @Dan Bron You're not just arguing against Peter, but against [Kingsley Amis](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eOlgr6f7IzIC&pg=PT141&lpg=PT141&dq=%22than+I+can+help%22+meaning&source=bl&ots=1bdHhLvRs7&sig=o1WK2HS4BhfTHCcwfsrpVs-8rpg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CSP-U938Ao-XaubfgMAM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22than%20I%20can%20help%22%20meaning&f=false).

Comment: You mean the Kingsley Amis who should be contradicted at regular intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, one shouldn't.

If you can help it, you won't do it.

> "I won't stay longer than I can help."

Maybe better is

> "I won't stay longer than I can manage."

meaning

> "I will not stay longer if I don't need to"

or alternatively

> "I will stay longer if I do need to."

Answer (score 0):

> they all sounded strange to me.

They are not:

"I couldn't help staying - I had come with John and he had to make the final speech."

"I won't stay longer than I can help [staying].

"I won't eat any more than I can eat."

"I won't pay more than I can afford."

Answer (score -1):

I can help,myself. Now focus on myself. The sentence is "I won't be longer than I can help". This will be the maximum time i will be there and not a second more because after a second i would not be able to help myself to stay at that particular place. The part "I can help" is supporting I won't be longer.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer after taking the [tour] and reading the [help] page.